# Angular ui-grid calendar dates in ui-grid header

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-calendar

I am new to angular js .I am working on employee leave application.Should i use angular ui-grid or angular ui-calender.
There are multiple
options for leave(single date) as  follows

1)planned leave 2)unplanned leave

from these i have to select one of these

which  i think i wont be able to do in ui-calender.But again if i go for angular ui-grid i want to display the dates in the column header for current month with day of ui-grid i dont know how to it.
        I can display multiple option in cell then. any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

I do not know it is a solution but you can use `headerTemplate` in `columnDefs` to specify what you need in header.